# limit at $+\infty$ of x(t) for $x'(t)=\sin(x(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the initial value problem:
$\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l}
x'(t) = \sin (x(t)),\ t\in\mathbb{R}\\ 
x(0)=x_0 \in \left]0,\pi\right[
\end{array}
\right.$

I am trying to find $\lim\limits_{t \to +\infty} x(t)$

What I did:

I showed that any solution verifies $x(t) \in \left]0, \pi\right[$.
I also verified that $x(t)$ is monotonic on $\mathbb{R}$, that the limit exists and that there is unique solution $x(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Suppose the limit is $L$. What is the limit of $x'(t)$ then?

Comment: If the limit exists the derivative of the limit is $0$, from this we get?

Comment: Assume that $x(t) \in (0, \pi)$ for $t\in[0,T]$. On this interval, $x$ is monotone increasing and $$T=\int_{x(0)}^{x(T)} \frac{dx}{\sin x}.$$ Starting from this, it is not hard to argue that $x(t) < \pi$ for all $t$ and that $x(t)\to\pi$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Just draw the phase portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit exists it means that $\lim_{t\to\infty} x'(t)\to0\iff \lim_{t\to\infty}\sin(x(t))\to0\iff \sin(\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t))\to0\iff \lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)\to0\lor \pi$ how can we conclude which one is the limit?

Answer (score 1):

It is also not so hard to find the explicit solution, which is $x(t) = 2 \arctan (e^t)$ up to a time shift. Then $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = \pi$ is straightforward.